# erase certain circles in pygame window

Tags: pygame

I have a pygame screen with multiple tree like objects which grows with each update. I also have to draw random circle which appear and disappear with each update.

I am not able to make the circles alone to disappear. If I try to redraw I loose the slowly incrementing tree structure also. Any help

Answer (score 0):

Using sprite groups (http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) you can put all the tree like objects into a sprite group designated for trees. Then at the end of the game loop you could blit the background onto the screen and call "tree_group.draw(screen)" to draw all your tree sprites wherever they may be on the screen. With that in place, you can simply draw a random circle wherever you'd like without worrying about taking corrective measures and trying to fix where the circle was drawn previously. Using sprite groups makes updating in game loops a breeze as well. Just call "tree_group.update(args)" and every object in the group will update with the arguments passed in.